# Keras: Extract features from siamese network for a single input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a siamese network trained Model in Keras like [this](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/). This Model expects two inputs and it then calculates the distance between these and generates a similarity score. But now I only want to extract the features and use some other techniques to find similar images. As a siamese network is basically one single (same) CNN by which both images are passed and now I don't have to calculate similarity between two, can I only pass a single image at a time and get the features from the aforementioned trained CNN?
I tried this `intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input[0],    outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)` as mentioned [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) but it throws a `ValueError` as the graph expects 2 inputs.

Adding screenshot of my `model.layers`
[image: hot]

Comment: The way you segment the model should be OK (assuming you use the right layers, which -from the link to the Keras page- would be the equivalent of `input_a` and `processed_a`). Can't say why you get the error with the information provided

Comment: Hi @GPhilo, thanks for the input. Once I save the network, I don't have access to `processed_a`. My saved model has layers - input0, input1, Model, Lambda at 0,1,2,3 respectively when I call model.layers. Hence I try `K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[2].outputs[0]])` as given in the second method in the second link but it gives `InvalidArgumentError`

Comment: You could try printing the `name` of the necessary layer's input and output before saving the model and then retrieve them by name. Are you sure `layers[2]` is the layer matching `processed_a`?

Comment: And this `Model(inputs=model.layers[0].input, outputs=model.layers[2].outputs[0])` throws `ValueError:Graph Disconnected`

Comment: @GPhilo done that, the problem is not the name, the model still expects 2 inputs

Comment: @deadcode can please share here how you fixed it. Even I am facing exactly same issue